# selecting checkbox in a table and getting the data of that row to be printed

Tags: javascript, struts2

i have a table in which the first column contains checkbox and the rest column contains some data. I want that the user can select multiple checkbox from the table and on the basis of selection 2 column from that particular row gets printed.

Comment: <table id="example" class="table active" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr class="success">
   <th><b>Select</b></th>
   <th><b>S No.</b></th>
   <th><b>Date</b></th>
   <th><b>Note</b></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>


 <tbody>
  <s:iterator value="rlist" status="rlistStatus">

   <tr>
    
    <td><s:checkbox name="checked" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
    <td><b><s:property value="SNo" /></b></td>
    <td id='id'><b><s:property value="RDate" /></b></td>
    <td id='id'><b><s:property value="RPointNote" /></b></td>
   </tr>

  </s:iterator>
 </tbody>
</table>
here is the code

Comment: Please move the code into the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Dear Roman 
i have a table which contains 4 column the first column contains a check box and the rest column contains some data. Other than this the page contains a print button
the user can check multiple checkboxes and when the user clicks on print button it should print other column of that row whose checkboxes has been checked